# A question on Vector addition.

Tags: vector-analysis

Is (A vector +B vector) always perpendicular to (A vector - B vector)?

Comment: Have you tried it with $B = \vec 0$?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not. Why do you think it would? Try almost any two random vectors in the basic spaces $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ , for example, with the usual inner product:

$$a:=\binom10,\,\,b:=\binom11\implies a+b=\binom21\;,\;\;a-b=\binom0{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try to get resultant from the parallelogram law, and you will see that $(\vec A + \vec B)$ and $(\vec A - \vec B)$  are perpendicular only when their magnitude is equal.

Resultant of $(\vec A + \vec B)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2AB\cos\theta}$ and resultant of $(\vec A - \vec B)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2AB\cos\theta}$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec A $ and $\vec B$.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let $a, b$ be two vectors in a vector space equipped with an inner product, the necessary condition would be: $\left\|a\right\| = \left\|b\right\|$.

The derivation is

\begin{align}
(a + b)(a - b)
= a*a - b*b 
= \left\|a\right\| - \left\|b\right\|
= 0
\end{align}